# Why not all key from Revel JSON response are capitalized?

Tags: go, revel

I'm trying to understand how to implement POST request using Revel framework.

[image]

**models/login.go**

```
package models

type LoginParam struct {
    Username string `form:"username" json:"username"`
    Password string `form:"password" json:"password"`
}

type Response struct {
    Message string `json:"message`
    Data    string `json:"data"`
}
```

**app/controllers/login.go**

```
package controllers

import (
    "mytestapi/app/models"
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/revel/revel"
)

type Login struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

func (c Login) DoLogin() revel.Result {
    var login models.LoginParam
    var res models.Response

    err := json.NewDecoder(c.Request.GetBody()).Decode(&login)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("JSON decode error: ", err)
    }

    res.Message = "OK"
    res.Data = login.Username + " " + login.Password

    defer c.Request.Destroy()
    return c.RenderJSON(res)
}
```

Postman gives this output:

> {   "Message": "OK",   "data": "foo barzzzz" }

Almost correct. On the JSON output, **M**essage instead of **m**essage is printed.
Why Message is capitalized, and data is not?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a double quote after the tag `message`:

```golang
type Response struct {
    Message string `json:"message`
    Data    string `json:"data"`
}
```